# How to use Google QR Code API to save QR image to database with PHP?

Tags: php, google-visualization, qr-code

I am working on an web application for buying ticket where when registering the user he will receive an e-mail that will contain QR CODE image .The QR Code will contain his userID which is an auto incremented integer .
Thank you!

Comment: _Side note_: _"the database is in phpmyadmin"_ - PHPMyAdmin is just a web based application for managing MySQL databases. Your application has nothing to do with PHPMyAdmin, unless you're hacking in that applications core files. Your database is MySQL.

Comment: _"I know I need to install a library but no idea how and where to include it."_ - Neither do we since we have _no idea_ what your application or your code looks like. Make some attempts and if you get stuck, come back, show us the code and explain your issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Real simple. Use Google. Fetch this URL (tweak the GET vars!) then header content type png echo it and exit!

https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=300x300&chl=https://nasa.gov

Here's the docs https://developers.google.com/chart/infographics/docs/qr_codes

```
<?php

$url = '
https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=300x300&chl=https://nasa.gov';
$qr = file_get_contents($url);
header('Content-Type: image/png');
echo $qr;
exit;
```